# How can I solve "prevent touch scrolling" in SwiperJS library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, swiper.js

Gif to show the problem:
[image]

```
 <Swiper
    className="panel-swiper"
    initialSlide={value}
    onSwiper={setSwiper}
    onSlideChange={handleSlideChanging}
    simulateTouch={false}
  >
    <SwiperSlide>Panel 0</SwiperSlide>
    <SwiperSlide>Panel 1</SwiperSlide>
    <SwiperSlide>Panel 2</SwiperSlide>
    <SwiperSlide>
      <League />
      <League />
      <League />
    </SwiperSlide>
    <SwiperSlide>Panel 4</SwiperSlide>
    <SwiperSlide>Panel 5</SwiperSlide>
    <SwiperSlide>Panel 6</SwiperSlide>
    <SwiperSlide>Panel 7</SwiperSlide>
    <SwiperSlide>Panel 8</SwiperSlide>
    <SwiperSlide>Panel 9</SwiperSlide>
  </Swiper>
```

As you can see when I want to use touch to scroll page, it prevented.
but using mouse wheel it's working properly correct.

I need to mention, I'm using SwiperJS.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved this problem, when I imported the extra modules (`A11y, Navigation, Pagination`), the problem went away.

```
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';
import { A11y, Navigation, Pagination } from 'swiper';
                            

                                <Swiper
                                    modules={[Navigation, Pagination, A11y]}
                                    spaceBetween={50}
                                    slidesPerView={1}
                                    navigation
                                    pagination={{ clickable: true }}
                                >
                                    <SwiperSlide>
                                        test
                                    </SwiperSlide>
                                </Swiper>
```

Comment: It could not solve my issue.

Comment: @Mirror sorry not able to fix

Comment: If you see the gif vertical touch scrolling prevented.